# How can I make a time string match up if the miliseconds do not match

Tags: python, windows-10

I am trying to make a clock that stops at a certain time. This is the code I currently have:

```py
import time as t
import datetime as dt
import os
    
tc = input("When do you want this to stop? (military time please) ")
exit = False
date = str(dt.datetime.now().date())
    
    
while (exit == False):
   if dt.datetime.now() == date + " " + tc + ":00.0000":
       exit = True
   else:
       print(dt.datetime.now())
       t.sleep(0.01)
       os.system('cls')
```

The problem is that the time never exactly gets to the perfect place for the parts less than a second so how do I get it to stop?

Comment: `dt.datetime.now()` is never going to equal a string anyway.

Comment: You shouldn't check for the exact time. Rather, check that now is *greater than* the target time.

Comment: simple: change dt.datetime.now() == date to dt.datetime.now() >=date.

Comment: I figured it out, I just needed to `[-6:]` on `dt.datetime.now()` to get it to work

Answer (score 0):

do you mean like this?

`if dt.datetime.now() >= date + " " + tc + ":00.0000"`

also please format the datetime.now() to the string you want 
using something like `datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the time has passed, something like

```
if dt.datetime.now() >= date + " " + tc + ":00.0000":
```

You'll probably have to fiddle with the available methods to get it to work, I don't know if there's a built in comparator in that library. But something along those lines just checking if the current time is past the desired time.